# SharePoint 2010 Jquery/JSON Rest Multiple OR Statement - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, sharepoint

I'm trying to build a multiple OR variable but I can't seem to get it to work.  Is my syntax or logic bad?

```
var category = i.Category == "Electric" ? "E" || i.Category == "Power Module" ? "PM" || i.Category == "Branch Office" ? "BO" : "";
```

From what I've been able to research || is an OR indicator and the ? denotes the result of the previous statement where the : "" is what happens if its neither.  Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if using the shorthand IF here is a good idea because of the ORs that you are trying to incorporate.  Have you considered a Switch statement that would assign a value to the variable based on the different conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ternary operator is fine in itself... (with the corrections Vadim suggested) but it looks very complicated. In this case I would prefer a switch statement like this:

```js
function whatsMyCategory(i) {
  var category = (i.Category == "Electric" ? "E" : i.Category == "Power Module" ? "PM" : i.Category == "Branch Office" ? "BO" : "");

  console.log("Category=" + category);

  var cat = "";
  switch (i.Category) {
    case "Electric":
      cat = "E";
      break;
    case "Power Module":
      cat = "PM"
      break;
    case "Branch Office":
      cat = "BO"
      break;
    default:
      cat = "";
  }

  console.log("Cat=" + cat);
}

whatsMyCategory({
  "Category": "Electric"
});
whatsMyCategory({
  "Category": "Power Module"
});
whatsMyCategory({
  "Category": "Branch Office"
});
whatsMyCategory({
  "Category": "Something different"
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I went with the bottom solution with the switch statement and that seemed to work perfectly.  Good to know about both solutions this will help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

You could build such an expression using [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var category = i.Category == "Electric" ? "E" : i.Category == "Power Module" ? "PM" : i.Category == "Branch Office" ? "BO" : "";
```

or *dynamically* by extracting first letter of category word, for example:

```
var category = i.Category.split(' ').map(function(item){return item[0]}).join('');
```